# Setting gvim tabwidth according to filetype

Tags: vim, tabs

Why doesn't my Gvim set tabwidth according file type ?

My `.gvimrc` has following code

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
autocmd BufRead *.svh       set tabstop=2
autocmd BufRead *.svh       set shiftwidth=2


:verbose set ts? sw?

  tabstop=2
        Last set from ~/.gvimrc
  shiftwidth=2
        Last set from ~/.gvimrc
```

Comment: After `:e foo.svh`, what does `:verbose set ts? sw?` tell you?  Make sure that foo.svh already exists:  BufRead is "Not used when the file doesn't exist."

Comment: Also you should use `setlocal`

Comment: `:verbose set ts? sw?` gave me 2(edited above). What is `setlocal` for

Comment: For `:setlocal`, read `:help global-local` and `:help :setlocal`.  I do not see what is wrong:  it looks like you wanted the `'tabstop'` option set to 2 for `*.svh` and it worked.

Comment: Despite having `tabstop=2` and `shiftwidth=2`, my tabs are 4 spaces long. Should I set something else ? I want default tab length to be 4 and 2 for *.svh files